# How do I fix my 2014 HP Pavilion (64) keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keys

I ran my 2014 HP Pavilion 64 on a 20.04 Ubuntu system for a while. However, after the last update on my system in November 2023, my <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> keys stopped working. I am a novice at this but in all sincerity, I have been using it(Ubuntu) for a while now, and would not go back to any other OS. Could anybody provide any assistance at all? I installed the new Ubuntu version (23.10) and the keys won't work either. As of right now, I am using an external keyboard.
Thanks

Comment: Your description implies to me hardware problems with your keyboard.  Have you booted another OS and see if it's any different? (eg. a *live* system)

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. I do not have an alternative OS maybe I should try one.

Comment: My suggestion of *live* means you can try it without install, Ubuntu media allows this, though to confirm its your hardware, I'd personally use a very different system to what you've tried already (ie. you mention 20.04 but not which stack (20.04 is a LTS thus had kernel stack choice) & 23.10, I'd likely try a non-Ubuntu such as Debian GNU/Linux, or if Ubuntu a very different stack to what you're using currently; ie. if your 20.04 is using HWE, I'd not try 22.04 using GA (same as 20.04) nor 22.04 using HWE (same as 23.10))...

Comment: I will definitely try with a windows live version from a stick, otherwise I will follow your suggestion to try Debian/GNU/Linux. I highly appreciate you are taking the time.